# Not able to edit text input react redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Unable to edit textinput after setting up value from db. The value gets changed by one character that one is recently typed while focusing out from that textinput. Initially, I am setting up each value of textinput by state property. Then edit mode I get that value from db and setting up through state property. After that, I am unable to edit in edit mode.

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Field,
    reduxForm
} from 'redux-form';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
    addEmployee
} from '../actions/employeeAction';
import {
    editEmployee
} from '../actions/employeeAction';
import {
    connect
} from 'react-redux';
import UploadImage from './uploadimage/uploadImage';
import {
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Init from './index';


const FIELDS = {
    firstname: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'First Name',
        key: 1,
        name: 'firstname',
        dbName: 'firstname'
    },
    lastname: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Last Name',
        key: 2,
        name: 'lastname',
        dbName: 'lastname'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Password',
        key: 3,
        name: 'password',
        dbName: 'password'
    },
    reenterpassword: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Re-password',
        key: 4,
        name: 'reenterpassword',
        dbName: 'reenterpassword'
    },
    age: {
        type: 'Number',
        label: 'Age',
        key: 5,
        name: 'age',
        dbName: 'age'
    },
    occupation: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Occupation',
        key: 6,
        name: 'occupation',
        dbName: 'occupation'
    },
    city: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'City',
        key: 7,
        name: 'city',
        dbName: 'city'
    },
    state: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'State',
        key: 8,
        name: 'state',
        dbName: 'state'
    },
    pin: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Pin',
        key: 9,
        name: 'pin',
        dbName: 'pin'
    },
    phone: {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Phone',
        key: 10,
        name: 'phone',
        dbName: 'phone'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'email',
        label: 'Email',
        key: 11,
        name: 'email',
        dbName: 'email'
    },
    dateOfJoin: {
        type: 'date',
        label: 'Date Of Join',
        key: 12,
        name: 'dateOfJoin',
        dbName: 'dateOfJoin'
    },
    uploadPhoto: {
        type: 'blob',
        label: 'Upload Image',
        key: 13,
        name: 'uploadPhoto',
        dbName: 'croppedImage'
    }
}

class PostNew extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.renderField = this.renderField.bind(this);
        this.onCroppedImgData = this.onCroppedImgData.bind(this);
        this.valueChange = this.valueChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            croppedData: undefined,
            header: 'Registration Form',
            createdUser: false
        };
        /********Initial setup for state for each text input********/
        _.each(FIELDS, (type, field) => {
            let dbState = type.dbName;
            this.state = {
                dbState: ""
            };
        });
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.header) {
            this.setState({
                header: this.props.header
            });
        }
        if (this.props.userData) {
            _.each(FIELDS, (type, field) => {
                let dbState = type.dbName;
                this.setState({
                    [dbState]: this.props.userData[dbState]
                });
            });
        }

    }
    callAttribute(field) {
        return <Field label = {
            field.label
        }
        key = {
            field.key
        }
        type = {
            field.type
        }
        name = {
            field.name
        }
        dbname = {
            field.dbName
        }
        component = {
            this.renderField
        }
        />
    }
    onCroppedImgData(data) {
        this.setState({
            croppedData: data
        });
    }
    valueChange(e, dbName) {
        if (this.props.userData) {
            /**********Setting state dynamically here and called onChange method of textinput.And textinput value changed one character while we focused out.*********/
            this.setState({
                [dbName]: e.target.value
            });
        }

    }
    renderField(field) {
        const {
            meta: {
                touched,
                error
            }
        } = field;
        const {
            label,
            type,
            key,
            name,
            dbname
        } = field;

        if (label === "Upload Image") {
            let src;
            if (this.props.userData) {
                src = this.props.userData[dbname];
            }
            return ( <
                div className = "upload-image" >
                <
                UploadImage message = "Upload Image"
                callbackImgCropped = {
                    this.onCroppedImgData
                }
                profileImg = {
                    src
                }
                /> <
                /div>
            )
        } else {
            let val;
            if (this.props.userData) {
                console.log("=====this.state[dbname]===", this.state[dbname]);
                val = this.state[dbname];
                if (dbname === "dateOfJoin") {
                    val = "";
                }
            }

            return ( <
                div className = "field-div" >
                <
                div >
                <
                span className = "label-name" > {
                    label
                } < /span> <
                input className = "form-input"
                key = {
                    key
                }
                type = {
                    type
                } { ...field.input
                }
                ref = {
                    name
                }
                value = {
                    this.state[dbname]
                }
                onChange = {
                    (e) => {
                        this.valueChange(e, dbname)
                    }
                }
                /> <
                span className = "error-msg" > {
                    touched ? error : ' '
                } < /span> <
                /div> <
                /div>

            );
        }

    }
    onSubmit(obj) {
        if (this.state.croppedData) {
            obj.croppedImage = this.state.croppedData;
        }
        if (this.props.userData) {
            obj.id = this.props.userData.id;
            console.log("edit operation");
            this.props.editEmployee(obj, (data) => {
                this.props.reset();
            });
        } else {
            if (this.state.croppedData) {
                obj.croppedImage = this.state.croppedData;
            }
            this.props.addEmployee(obj, (data) => {
                this.setState({
                    createdUser: true
                });
                this.props.reset();
            });
        }

    }
    render() {
        const {
            handleSubmit,
            pristine,
            reset,
            submitting
        } = this.props;
        if (this.state.createdUser) {
            return ( < Redirect to = "/" / > );
        } else {
            return ( <
                div className = "form-div" >
                <
                div className = "form-header" > {
                    this.state.header
                } < /div> <
                form className = "employee-form"
                onSubmit = {
                    handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))
                } > {
                    _.map(FIELDS, this.callAttribute.bind(this))
                } <
                div className = "form-button" >
                <
                button type = "submit"
                disabled = {
                    submitting
                } >
                Submit <
                /button> <
                button type = "button"
                disabled = {
                    pristine || submitting
                }
                onClick = {
                    reset
                } >
                Clear Values <
                /button> <
                /div> <
                /form> <
                /div>  
            );
        }

    }
}

function validate(values) {
    const errors = {};
    _.each(FIELDS, (type, field) => {
        if (!values[field] && type.type != "blob" && type.label != "Date Of Join") {
            if (type.type == "email") {
                errors[field] = `Enter an ${field}`;
            } else {
                errors[field] = `Enter a ${field}`;
            }

        } else if (type.type == "email" && values[field]) {
            if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values[field])) {
                errors[field] = 'Invalid email address'
            }
        } else if (type.name == "reenterpassword" && values[field] !== values['password']) {
            errors[field] = 'Password mismatched.Please reenter password.';
        }
    });
    return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
    form: 'PostNewForm'
})(connect(null, {
    addEmployee,
    editEmployee
})(PostNew));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Yes got the solution ...We need to include  "change" method from 'redux-form' and we need to dispatch the method with 3 arguments.

this.props.dispatch(change('PostNewForm', [dbName], e.currentTarget.value));
1st argument = form name 
2nd argument = state name
3rd argument = value
Below is the working code...These redux form controls are uncontrolled .so we need to include {change} from redux-form.

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Field, reduxForm,change } from 'redux-form';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import {addEmployee} from '../actions/employeeAction';
    import {editEmployee} from '../actions/employeeAction';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import UploadImage from './uploadimage/uploadImage';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Init from './index'; 


    const FIELDS = {
      firstname:{
         type:'input',
         label:'First Name',
         key:1,
         name:'firstname',
         dbName:'firstname'
      },
      lastname:{
         type:'input',
         label:'Last Name',
         key:2,
         name:'lastname',
         dbName:'lastname'
      },
      password:{
         type:'password',
         label:'Password',
         key:3,
         name:'password',
         dbName:'password'
      },
      reenterpassword:{
         type:'password',
         label:'Re-password',
         key:4,
         name:'reenterpassword',
         dbName:'reenterpassword'
      },
      age:{
         type:'Number',
         label:'Age',
         key:5,
         name:'age',
         dbName:'age'
      },
      occupation:{
         type:'input',
         label:'Occupation',
         key:6,
         name:'occupation',
         dbName:'occupation'
      },
      city:{
         type:'input',
         label:'City',
         key:7,
         name:'city',
         dbName:'city'
      },
      state:{
         type:'input',
         label:'State',
         key:8,
         name:'state',
         dbName:'state'
      },
      pin:{
         type:'input',
         label:'Pin',
         key:9,
         name:'pin',
         dbName:'pin'
      },
      phone:{
         type:'input',
         label:'Phone',
         key:10,
         name:'phone',
         dbName:'phone'
      },
      email:{
         type:'email',
         label:'Email',
         key:11,
         name:'email',
         dbName:'email'
      },
      dateOfJoin:{
         type:'date',
         label:'Date Of Join',
         key:12,
         name:'dateOfJoin',
         dbName:'dateOfJoin'
      },
      uploadPhoto:{
         type:'blob',
         label:'Upload Image',
         key:13,
         name:'uploadPhoto',
         dbName:'croppedImage'
      }
    }

    class PostNew extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.renderField = this.renderField.bind(this);
        this.onCroppedImgData = this.onCroppedImgData.bind(this);
        this.valueChange = this.valueChange.bind(this);
        var stateData = [];
        var constructState='{"croppedData":"undefined","header":"Registration Form","createdEditUser":false';
        _.each(FIELDS,(type,field)=>{
           let dbState = type.dbName;
           constructState = constructState+',"'+dbState+'":""';
        });
        constructState = constructState + '}';
        this.state = JSON.parse(constructState);
      }
      componentWillMount(){
        if(this.props.header){
          this.setState({header:this.props.header});
        }
        if(this.props.userData){
          _.each(FIELDS,(type,field)=>{
             let dbState = type.dbName;
             this.setState({[dbState]:this.props.userData[dbState]});
          });
        }
      }
      callAttribute(field){
        return <Field label={field.label} key={field.key} type={field.type}  name={field.name} dbname={field.dbName} component={this.renderField} />
      }
      onCroppedImgData(data)
      {
        this.setState({croppedData:data});
      }
      valueChange(e,dbName){
        this.setState({[dbName]:e.currentTarget.value});
        this.props.dispatch(change('PostNewForm', [dbName], e.currentTarget.value));

      }
      renderField(field){
        const {meta:{touched,error}} = field;
        const {label,type,key,name,dbname} = field;

        if(label === "Upload Image"){
          let src;
          if(this.props.userData){
            src = this.props.userData[dbname];
          }
           return(
              <div className="upload-image">
                  <UploadImage message="Upload Image" callbackImgCropped={this.onCroppedImgData} profileImg={src}/>
              </div>
           )
        }else{
          let val;
          let placeholder = 'Please enter your '+label;
          if(this.props.userData){

             val = this.state[dbname];
             if(dbname === "dateOfJoin"){
              val = "";
             }
          }
          console.log("=====this.state[dbname]===",this.state[dbname]);
          return(
            <div className="field-div">
              <div >
                 <span className="label-name">{label}</span>
                 <input className="form-input" key={key} type={type} {...field.input}  ref={name} value={this.state[dbname]} onChange={(e) => {this.valueChange(e,dbname)}} placeholder={placeholder}/>
                 <span className="error-msg">{touched ? error : ' '}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }

      }
      onSubmit(obj){
        if(this.state.croppedData){
          obj.croppedImage = this.state.croppedData;
        }
        if(this.props.userData){
          obj.id = this.props.userData.id;
          console.log("edit operation");
          this.props.editEmployee(obj,(data) => {
             this.setState({createdEditUser:data.status});
             this.props.reset();
          });
        }else{
          if(this.state.croppedData){
            obj.croppedImage = this.state.croppedData;
          }
          this.props.addEmployee(obj,(data) => {
            this.setState({createdEditUser:true});
            this.props.reset();     
          });
        }

      }
      render(){
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
        if(this.state.createdEditUser){
          return( <Redirect to="/signin" /> );
        }else{
          return(
            <div className="form-div">
              <div className="form-header">{this.state.header}</div>
              <form className="employee-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
              {_.map(FIELDS,this.callAttribute.bind(this))}
              <div className="form-button">
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                  Submit
                </button>
                <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
                  Clear Values
                </button>
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>  
          );
        }

      }
    }

    function validate(values){
       const errors = {};
       _.each(FIELDS,(type,field)=>{
         if(!values[field] && type.type != "blob" && type.label !="Date Of Join"){
          if(type.type == "email"){
            errors[field] = `Enter an ${field}`;
          }else{
            errors[field] = `Enter a ${field}`;
          }

         }
         else if(type.type == "email" && values[field]){
            if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values[field])) {
              errors[field] = 'Invalid email address'
            }
          }else if(type.name == "reenterpassword" && values[field]!==values['password']){
              errors[field] = 'Password mismatched.Please reenter password.';
          }
      });
       return errors;
    }

    export default reduxForm({
      validate,
      fields : _.keys(FIELDS),
      form:'PostNewForm'
    })(connect(null,{addEmployee,editEmployee})(PostNew));
```